# Possible to do GWT 2.2 Maintenance in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have the task to do some work on our GWT 2.2 code base with

the GWT Config, etc, used, is long gone. And I must use Eclipse Kepler.

Does current GWT provide backward compatability that far?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The version of the Eclipse plugin is independent of the version of the SDK you use in your project. You can use the newest plugin with GWT projects that needs older versions of the SDK.

You have to set this up in the project properties.